# AndEngine updating screen

Tags: android, andengine

I have a live wallpaper which I created using the android canvas. Upon testing, I felt it necessary to harness the power of OpenGL, and so am experimenting with AndEngine. I am wondering how I can achieve the following.

I have a background image that fills the whole screen, with many smaller bitmaps floating over the top (not animated movements)

So far I have this for the background image:

```
    @Override
public void onLoadResources()
{
    mtexture = new Texture(1024, 1024, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
    TextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
    mtextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.createFromResource(mtexture , this, R.drawable.background1, 0, 0);
    this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.mtexture );
}

@Override
public Scene onLoadScene(){
    final Scene scene = new Scene(1);

    Sprite background = new Sprite(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH*2, CAMERA_HEIGHT, mtextureRegion ) 
    SpriteBackground sb = new SpriteBackground(background);
    scene.setBackground(sb);
    scene.setBackgroundEnabled(true);
    return scene;
}
```

This works fine for the background, but I require moving sprites.

In my canvas code, I do the following to update the position & physics of the moving objects and draw the canvas every few ms

```
        private final Runnable drawScreen = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            drawFrame();
        }};
```

-

```
    void drawFrame() {
        final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();

        Canvas c = null;
        try {
            c = holder.lockCanvas();
            if (c != null) {
                    //draw
            }
        } finally {
            if (c != null) holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }

        mHandler.removeCallbacks(drawScreen);
        mHandler.postDelayed(drawScreen, 10);
    }
```

What is the appropriate way to do this on AndEngine? do I use the same code and substitute openGL calls?

I had a look at `GLEngine`, am I supposed to send Runnables to the `GlThread` queue?

EDIT - I think I found the answer...an UpdateHandler. But how can I inform the handler of an update (i.e. to call the `onUpdate` method). If I make a timed Handler, what happens if I call too often, does a queue of requests build up?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, don't use the constructor `Scene(int)`, it's deprecated. Use `Scene()` instead.

Correct, you should use an update handler.
You can create an `UpdateHandler`, and then register it to your scene:

```
scene.registerUpdateHandler(mUpdateHandler);
```

This way, the code in `mUpdateHandler.onUpdate` method is executed each time the scene updates (Each frame.). You *don't* call it manually. If you want to stop it, call:

```
scene.unregisterUpdateHandler(mUpdateHandler);
```

So, the `onUpdate` method is *always* executed in the UpdateThread, so you can be sure you can do any change to entities you want there. So you can move around and sprite you want, etc...

By the way, why is the background's width `CAMERA_WIDTH*2`? It means that only the left half of your sprite is shown. If you don't plan moving the camera, then the right half won't ever show.